# Pesapal OpenCart callback

Tags: php, opencart-3

I'm trying to redirect a user to `checkout/success` page after handling a callback. It however does not redirect and remains on a blank page with the callback url. The failure doesn't even hit. The funny thing is that it works as expected on my local server, but when uploaded online it does not work. Am I missing something?
Here is my callback function:

```
  public function callback(){

    if( $_GET["pesapal_merchant_reference"] || $_GET["pesapal_transaction_tracking_id"] ){
    $merchant_reference = $_GET['pesapal_merchant_reference'];
    $transaction_tracking_id = $_GET['pesapal_transaction_tracking_id'];

    $this->load->model('extension/payment/pesapal');
    $this->model_extension_payment_pesapal->insertPesapalTransaction($merchant_reference, $transaction_tracking_id);
    $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('checkout/success', '', true));

    } else {
    $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('checkout/failure', '', true));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you enable error logging and share the log data?